# Loop space structures on $RP^\infty$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I am interested in infinite loop structures on the infinite dimensional projective space $\mathbb{R} P^\infty$. Is it unique? I think this has to be known in work of May, and If so, then I presume its proof should boil down to some simple fact. Can anyone please give me some advise on this, and the simple fact that one might expect?!

Comment: the infinite dimensional real projective space is $K(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z},1)$. Suppose there is an other infinite loop structure different form the standard one, clearely, $B\Omega K(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z},1)\simeq K(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z},1)$ as infinity loop space. But $ \Omega K(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z},1)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ as a set and as a group with two elements. Therefore the infinite loop structure on $K(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z},1)$ has to be equivalent to the standard one.

Comment: An other  formulation of your question is that $[E_{\infty}, End_{operad}(\mathbf{R}P^{\infty})]=\ast$. Where the [,] is the morphisms set in the homotopy category of operads, and $End_{Operad}$ is the endomorphism operad.

Comment: @AmraniIlias, thank you for your answer. It seems to me that your second answer does consider a loop space structure on $\mathbb{Z}/2$ rather than $K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1)$!?!

Comment: what do you mean by second answer ? Operad stuff ?

Comment: No, that EM space bit.

Comment: Well, K(Z/2,1) is connected, suppose that it has an other infinite loop structure, denoted by $\mu$. Using the bar structure with respect to $\mu$,, we have that $B_{\mu}\Omega K(Z/2,1)$ is equivalent to $K(Z/2,1)$ as infinite loop space with respect to the multiplicative structure $\mu$, but $\Omega K(Z/2,1)$ has a unique infinite loop structure, thus $B_{\mu}\Omega K(Z/2,1)$ is equivalent to $K(Z/2,1)$ as an infinite loop space where $K(Z/2,1)$ has the standard structure of loop space, hope it is clear :)

Comment: @AmraniIlias, thanks. Somehow it feels as the same answer as Neil's, but using Bar construction. Am I right that the bottom line of your argument is that since there is only one non-trivial group structure on $\mathbb{Z}/2$ then $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ admits a unique delooping?! just not sure what I am seeing this so late!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essentially by definition, the category of infinite loop spaces is equivalent to the category of $(-1)$-connected spectra.  Thus, you are asking about $(-1)$-connected spectra $X$ such that there exists an equivalence $\Omega^\infty X\simeq\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ of spaces (ignoring any infinite loop structures).  From such an equivalence we see that $\pi_*X$ is the same as $\pi_*\mathbb{R}P^\infty$, and so consists of a single $\mathbb{Z}/2$ in degree $1$.  Thus, there is only one possibility for $X$, by the standard argument for uniqueness of Eilenberg-MacLane spectra.